# Extend from library class, how to then have the library call derived classes method

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am wondering if this is possible. Again, the problem is:

> How can I extend from a libraries class, then have the library call a
>   function inside the derived class?

Obviously the library has already been built/compiled before the code which uses inheritance is written (shown below as DerivedClass). I want to abstract away from the user as much as possible. And to do this I have the following set up (includes left out for simplicity):

LibraryClass is a class in a .lib that I have created.

```
LibraryClass.h
class LibraryClass{
public:
    virtual void MyMethod() { }
};
```

DerivedClass inherits from this library:

```
DerivedClass.h
Class DerivedClass: public LibraryClass {
public:
    virtual void MyMethod();
};
```

If I define MyMethod in the DerivedClass source file as follows:

```
DerivedClass.cpp
void DerivedClass::MyMethod() {
    cout << "it works!" << endl;
}
```

Is there any way for the library to call the derived class' method? I thought to pass a DerivedClass object in to the library as a pointer, but the library doesnt have access to the header to include it because it is already compiled in to the .lib.

I have seen this done before (Urho3D), do they use black magic or am I missing something simple?

Comment: How about using the templates?

Comment: I dont think a template is quite the right way to go? Please correct me but a template would not help with somehow passing the a pointer(?) to the derived class to the library?

Comment: Can you show us the use case of your library? I mean how it's called, such that you want it to call the derived class?

Comment: I mentioned in the post above that I thought to pass a DerivedClass object into the library as a pointer, then refer to the derived class through the virtual functions. This works but requires the user to write a main function.
Ideally 'main' would be defined in the library such that the user does not have to define an entry point. Instead they would write a class that extends/inherits from the library base class, [this is where I get fuzzy] then when the library calls a method from its own base class the derived class (virtual?) function that the user defined is run instead.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding here. The decision of what function to call is made at compile-time, not in the compiled sources. That's what your library's header is good for. You include it (even if the sources are pre-compiled), and then the compiler decides at compile-time what calls will be made. Whether your library is pre-compiled is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what *dynamic dispatch* (known in C++ as `virtual`) does: given a `Base*` (or `Base&`) that refers to an object of a derived type, a call to a virtual function will find the override even without any declaration of `Derived` (and thus even if the call was “compiled first”).

As to your “library-provided `main`” idea, that’s a lot harder: in general, how would he library know how to *construct* your object, and what would it do if you linked against [*two* “extending classes”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)?

But it is possible, if the library designs for it: have the library provide a global pointer variable (which it assigns in `main` if you want to have a default), and have the extension class’s constructor assign `this` to it.  Then just define a global object of that class type.  If you need no default behavior, you can also just declare and call, but not define, an initialization function in the library and leave it to the extension to define it.